# Count number of identical rows in MySQL with PHP

Tags: php, sql, count, duplicates

I have a table in MySql with a list of keywords. Each keyword was stored in a new row once it was entered by a user on this site.

I have the following query in PHP:

```
SELECT * FROM keywords GROUP BY query
```

Which gets all the keywords from MySql, and only shows one of each incase of duplicate keywords. So the output is something like:

```
Dog
Cat
Lion
Fong
```

When I'm using `$update['query'];`

But I'd like to count how many times each keyword appears in the database, so the output would be, for example:

```
Dog  (2)
Cat  (3)
Lion (1)
Fong (1)
```

And I'm trying to figure out what the SQL query should be, and how to print it using PHP.

Comment: At this moment I'd be happy with the simplest solution, but if youre feeling creative I'd love to learn how to do this with/without being case sensitive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT query, COUNT(1) AS rpt_count FROM keywords GROUP BY query
```

and in PHP you would access the columns using `$update['query']` and `$update['rpt_count']`

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *, count(*) as cnt FROM keywords GROUP BY query
```

Comment: Alternatively, use `COUNT(*) AS count`

Comment: @Ryan - Yes an alias should have been there. Updated.

Answer (score 1):

Use `SELECT *, COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM keywords GROUP BY query`.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *, count(1) FROM keywords GROUP BY query
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT query, COUNT(query) FROM keywords GROUP BY query
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT keyword, COUNT(*) FROM keywords GROUP BY keyword;
```